# Ubuntu 15.04 - after hard power boot, it never comes back or it boots but then it does not behave correctly

Tags: boot, power-management, 15.04, bug-reporting, autostart

I have a kiosk running with Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit, which is connected to a 47" screen, on boot it starts Google Chrome.

Now the Ubuntu 15.04 needs to be powered off (6PM) and powered on (8AM). When powered off is done (pulling out the power plug) and then powered on, the system sometime stays for-ever in the Ubuntu splash screen or it boots but then it does not execute my script at all.

`~/runme.sh` script which is configured as autorun using following tool

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to systemd : http://www.tecmint.com/manage-services-using-systemd-and-systemctl-in-linux/ If not, maybe there is something wrong with your script (Enter some debug-info into your script, to wee whether it is executed or not)

Answer (score 0):

You can look through the things that went wrong on the splash screen, if you, as I remember, press UP/DOWN to toggle "text" boot mode.

It will hide usual ubuntu greeting logo and display inline info messages: search for warn or error.

Comment: YES - alt+ctrl+f1 or so i remember that one, i will try, if you find some more reference please edit in the answer which i can test one by one.

Comment: No, I meant on boot you usually see Ubuntu Logo, which you experience to see for a while. While you see Ubuntu Logo, press UP or DOWN to see messages that system carefully displays for you. Among them can be an issue that makes OS stuck on boot.